# Delete first word of each line of text file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file formatted like this:

> username coins

I need to remove the username from the the line in Notepad++. Just removing the first word in each line

Comment: Are the first words of each line the same?

Comment: Could you give a larger example of what is in the file?

Comment: What characters are allowed in the username?

Answer (score 3):

Try using a regex in the Replace:

```
^([\w\-]+)
```

(There is a space at the end of this regex to include the trailing spaces).

Replace with nothing, change the Search Mode to Regular Expression..

Answer (score 2):

Search > Replace...

Find what: `^[^\s]+\s`
Replace with: (blank)
Search mode: Regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Delete word and space at the beginning of the line

Find: `^\w+\s(.)`

Replace with: `\1`

`^` beginning of the line
`\w+` first word
`\s` space
`(.)` tag the rest of the line

`\1` only include the rest of the line